Resources for learning Chinese dialects: Should we centralize this like we did mandarin chinese
This is a question in the same light as Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese: should we have it at all? 
Most of these questions are scattered and not formatted or maintained to the same standard as the central question, Examples:
Useful resources for learning Taiwanese?
How to start learning Cantonese?
Resources for learning Shanghainese 
So would we benefit from having a centralized post to keep all the resources in one place where it can be maintained. survey rules as always:

Vote this question up, if you want the community wiki to exist. 
Vote this question down, if you think it shouldn't exist.

Post any discussion points below

A community wiki makes sense here and resources like these evolve overtime.

For most cases,foreigners learning Chinese is to chat with more Chinese people, and different kinds of places with different kinds of dialects. That's not a union one. So We should learn madarin Chinese as the standard one.

I think they could be created as the need arises and also if there was sufficient material to share as a base. Maybe we should have a clearly defined meta-question which outlines what is required before we allow a new dialect resources question to be created.
I guess if this gets some support here we could ask a follow up question.
Also it has already been a few days and this question hasn't received much support, maybe you could start a new meta question asking for people to provide input into a resources question for Cantonese (or some other dialect if you feel you have enough material). 

2 out of the 3 link questions are already CW posts so I think if we could close them and bring the content into a central location it would be a good start. In terms of support this post only has 7 views, I think our meta is a little under visited more then this question being under supported. Not sure on the U/D vote ratio as I'm still 150 rep short on this SE but it doesn't seem poorely received

Not sure of next step, Can I go ahead and create the resource and link in and classify links from relevant post ect... or should I leave it to the Mod team to create or are we not going ahead with the CW?

@50-3 Thanks for sticking on this, I'm going to try and get a quick consensus from the chat room. If we get no input over 2 days then just go ahead.
